# How to use money data type in Java, SQL, ORM

Tags: java, sql, orm, types, currency

What are best practises in using money data type in Java application? Money should be in double variable? What about rounding, currencies and so on. Are special libraries for this? And what about ORM and SQL in most popular databases. As I know not in all SQL engines is Money data type. In that case `NUMERIC(15,2)`, `DECIMAL(15,2)` or REAL data type should be use?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> What are best practises in using money data type in Java application?

Use BigDecimal. Using any primitive *will* lead to precision problems sooner or later.

> And what about ORM and SQL in most popular databases.

Hibernate (and probably all others) can handle BigDecimal just fine. And it translates to the appropriate database type, which is usually DECIMAL.

Comment: Do you then just store the cents?

Comment: No, the big decimal contains information about where the separator is. It translates to a regular decimal in the DB. Besides, just storing the cents is a tricky solution: while it might make sense for some currencies with only 2 fraction digits, there are a few currencies that contains 3 fraction digits, some that have either 2 or 3 fraction digits, and a few have none. Not to mention that some things are priced with 3 fraction digits, even if the currency has only 2 fraction digits.

Answer (score 19):

You should use `BigDecimal` to represent monetary values.

**From Bloch, J., Effective Java, 2nd ed, Item 48:**

> The `float` and `double` types are
>   particularly ill-suited for monetary
>   calculations because it is impossible
>   to represent 0.1 (or any other
>   negative power of ten) as a `float` or
>   `double` exactly.
>
> For example, suppose you have $1.03
>   and you spend 42c. How much money do
>   you have left?
>
> ```
> System.out.println(1.03 - .42);
> ```
>
> prints out `0.6100000000000001`.
>
> The right way to solve this problem is
>   to use `BigDecimal`, `int` or `long`
>   for monetary calculations.

For SQL, I use `NUMERIC(19,2)`.

Answer (score 4):

In development circles, it is commonly considered best practice to use BigDecimal for money in Java.  That is not to say it is always better than using double IMHO, but I would suggest you start with BigDecimal.

For SQL I suggest using a matching type NUMERIC or DECIMAL for BigDecimal and REAL for double.

Its is worth noting that all the investment banks and trading houses I have worked for use double with rounding for money (in C++ and Java). Conversely I have never seen BigDecimal used, but I have seen NUMERIC used in databases. For accounting purposes use BigDecimal.

Answer (score -1):

Create BigDecimal from String, not from doulbe (float).

```
double doubleValue = 35.7;
BigDecimal fromDouble = new BigDecimal(doubleValue);
BigDecimal fromString = new BigDecimal("35.7");

boolean decimalsEqual = fromDouble.equals(fromString);

System.out.println("From double: " + fromDouble + " " + fromString.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
System.out.println("decimalsEqual: " + decimalsEqual");
```

Prints

```
From double: 35.7000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125 35.7
decimalsEqual: false
```

Also I had an issue when big decimal was stored as a double in mongo. Then BigDecimal constructor with double argument was called.

To solve this, we had converters that converted `BigDeciaml` to `String` for persistance.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.convert.ReadingConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions;

import java.math.BigDecimal;


@Configuration
public class CustomMongoConversionsConfig {

    @Bean
    public Converter<BigDecimal, String> bigdecimalWriteConverter() {
       return new BigDecimalToStringConverter();
    }

    @WritingConverter
    public static class BigDecimalToStringConverter implements Converter<BigDecimal, String> {

        @Override
        public String convert(final @NonNull BigDecimal source) {
            return source.toPlainString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you suggested, only implies that "don't use Float to construct a BigDecimal" because the nature of float which is not precise; it is due to the way how it is stored in computer, not because of the usage of BigDecimal. You can use BigDecimal and in the meanwhile avoid the constructor with float. I noticed that and since then, I only use string constructor.