# getFloat isn't there in java to get Float datatype

Tags: java, android, floating-point

Didn't able to find `getFloat` method for float data type. Whereas it shows some default method like `getString()`, `getInt()`, `getDouble()`. But my issue is I want to get this into float.

I tried using `getInt` but it gives rounded number not floating point

```
trade.client_sgxbfmtm = String.valueOf(singleRow.getInt("client_sgxbfmtm"));
```

Comment: getDouble() returns float.

Comment: If anything `getDouble` returns a number that is more precise than a `float`. Just get it as `double` and then cast it to `float`. By the way, do you have any particular reason to really need a `float` instead of a `double`?

Comment: What is tye type of `singleRow`?

Comment: As i am dealing with stock market data so it's in Floating point then i have to get it in Float but in java we have only getDouble and getString,  getInt, getBoolean only not getFloat.

Comment: String type but i tried to chang eit to float then in recyclerview adapter holder setText error is coming.

Comment: Wait, you're dealing with money using `float`s?? That's not going to end well.

Comment: i am getting data in json format and it is in float so in my android application i want it to display like same.

Comment: @Abhishek that doesn't make sense. In JSON a number is a number, not a `float` in particular. If you use `float` (or `double`, for that matter) [you **WILL** get rounding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826637/133203). Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca just noticed it looks like OP is going back to a string, so `getString` might be the best choice.  no point potentially changing the value when converting to/from via another type if you're going from a string to a string.

Comment: @SamMason can i perform some addition and multiplication,  subtraction by using getString.

Comment: @Abhishek no, but the code you posted isn't doing that.  You can construct a `BigDecimal` from a `String` and then operate on that.

Answer (score 2):

Update: if this is financial information then you likely don't want to use IEE754 floating point values.  These are binary formats, so can't represent values like `0.1` accurately.  Given that you seem to be wanting to convert back to string, I'd assume that you might be able to do something like:

```
trade.client_sgxbfmtm = singleRow.getString("client_sgxbfmtm");
```

and so not introduce any inaccuracy by converting to an IEEE float and back again.  This way your code doesn't know or care that the value contained in the string might be numeric.  If you're actually doing something with the number, then the comments suggesting the use of `BigDecimal` might be better.  But if you're just converting back to `String` then there's no point in going via anything.

---

A `double` follows the [same standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) as a `float`, just to a higher precision.  Hence using `getDouble` and then casting to a `float` is likely what you want to be doing.

Moreover, most contemporary CPUs are able to work with (64bit) `double`s at the [same speed](https://uops.info/) as (32bit) `float`s.  The only practical difference comes when you're dealing with large, densely packed arrays of them (i.e. thousands or millions of items) where the space savings make sense, or you're using specialised maths libraries that make use of vectorised operations.